# PHP $GLOBALS missing $_SERVER

Tags: php, global-variables, environment-variables

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php :

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are
>   currently defined in the global scope of the script.

So, following code must display that $GLOBALS var has `_SERVER`, `_ENV` (if it is enabled in variables_order in php.ini) and `_REQUEST` keys:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

The result is:

- Under nginx + php-fpm: missing `_SERVER`, `_ENV`, `_REQUEST`
- Under cli: missing `_ENV`, `_REQUEST`

Hmm.. perhaps there is smth in docs about this behavior? I've looked through every page for each variable:

- `_SERVER`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
- `_ENV`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php
- `_REQUEST`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

And i have found no mentions about such behaviour. Why it works like that?

I have installed php using debian package from http://www.dotdeb.org/ repo (nothing was compiled manually)... Currently running with nginx + php5-fpm.
Is that a php bug?

Comment: And what if you did `var_dump($_SERVER);` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but look at the [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) ini setting

Comment: $_SERVER is also a superglobal variable, same as $GLOBALS, that's why it's not stored in the $GLOBALS: `This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.` and `$_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these;servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here...`

Comment: @ZlatanO. Can't find such statement in docs (that _SERVER should not appear in $GLOBALS). _SERVER is variable defined in the global space, usual variable. It use different storage (not zval) or smth else? why?

Comment: Read more on php.net, and you can make the same conclusion yourself.

Comment: @ZlatanO. i am reading php.net every day, if i could find it by myself - i won't ask about it there.

Comment: @trueツ - It is a superglobal variable, if you like it or not. More on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php (see Notes section of the page...) and conclude a conclusion yourself...

Comment: @ZlatanO. `$_GET` and `$_POST` are also superglobals, and they are also present in `$GLOBALS` as OP commented. Also, in a rapid test, I see `$_SERVER` (and all other superglobals) in `var_dump($GLOBALS)`

Comment: @ZlatanO. I see same notes about _GET or _POST vars, which are also filled in by web server, but i can see them in the `$GLOBALS` var.

Comment: I've tested and removing 'S' from `variables_order` seems to not affect `$GLOBALS` in my computer.

Comment: @ZlatanO. My collegue said that _SERVER var does not appears in GLOBALS for security reasons - not to be overwritten, but i can't find such statement too in docs...

Comment: @true ツ: "for security reasons" --- this doesn't sound true

Comment: @zerkms i agree with you - because i can overwrite `_SERVER` var values.

Comment: I just checked, and on my setup `$_SERVER` is present in `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @thibauts under cli or webserver? if webserver, which one?

Comment: Checked, too. Apache with PHP as module running. `_SERVER` exists in `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @Boldewyn thank you, i will try to look through in nginx and php5-fpm forums then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a bug on php.net website, and php team answered: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65223

Summary:

> This is not a bug. super-globals (aka. auto globals) are not added
>   to symbol tables by default for performance reasons unless the parser
>   sees need. i.e.
>
> `<?php $_SERVER; print_r($GLOBALS); ?>`
>
> will list it. You can also control this using auto_globals_jit in
>   php.ini:
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit

Thanks php team so answer so fast!