# Difference in PHP GLOBALS between apache/linux versions

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

This might be a better way to ask a question I have about php and apache.  I have two servers and they have very different global variables when I `print_r($GLOBALS)` from php.  The differences are below.  Can someone explain why the test server call doesn't show ANY `_SERVER` settings?

—————— configuration from test server running Ubuntu 13.10 ———————

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
            [r] => 2
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [__utma] => etc
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
)
```

———— configuration from production server running Ubuntu 12.04 ——————

```
Array
(
    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_GET] => Array
        (
            [r] => 1
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [__utma] => etc
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [_REQUEST] => Array
        (
            [r] => 1
        )

    [_SERVER] => Array
        (
            [HTTPS] => on
            [SSL_TLS_SNI] => tgg.xxx.com
            [HTTP_HOST] => tgg.xxx.com
            [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
            [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
            [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
            [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
            [HTTP_COOKIE] => xxx
            [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
            [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
            [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at tgg.xxx.com Port 443

            [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
            [SERVER_NAME] => tgg.xxx.com
            [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.241.179.123
            [SERVER_PORT] => 443
            [REMOTE_ADDR] => 67.79.197.222
            [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/xxx
            [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
            [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/xxx/index.php
            [REMOTE_PORT] => 60665
            [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
            [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
            [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
            [QUERY_STRING] => r=1
            [REQUEST_URI] => /index.php?r=1
            [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
            [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
            [REQUEST_TIME] => 1395338407
        )

    [ignoreAuth] => 1
)
```

Comment: does `print_r($_SERVER);` work on it ?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545710/php-globals-missing-server

Comment: Check if you have [`auto-globals-jut`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit) set on your php.ini files. Chances are one has it and the other doesn't.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Answer (score 0):

Check if both `php.ini` files are the same. 
the core php.ini directives allow you to get/set the PHP setup configuration. So, try to set  `auto-globals-jut = 1` before using `print_r(...)`
see [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit)

Comment: I guess I should have put an answer in :)